# How to configure SMTP route in Microsoft email server

Tags: email, routes, smtp, windows-server-2003

I need to configure SMTP routing to another email server in standart Windows Server 2003 tool - Manage Your Server.

For example in hMailServer tool this problem solving by next principle:
All outcoming messages that ends by **@domain1** routes to **hostname.domain.com**

How to configure a similar thing by Windows Server tools?